# Proving that set is Jordan measurable

Tags: measure-theory

I have troubles with proving that set is Jordan measurable.
For example if I have closed ball $x^2+y^2\le a^2$, i need to prove that it is Jordan Measurable.
So, set is Jordan measurable if it is bounded and the measure of set of limit points is $0$.
For this example it is obvious that the set is bounded, but not sure how to prove that outer measure is zero. I'm not sure i even understand what outer measure is, because here we have limit point $(a,0)$ for example. and intuitively that should mean that outer bound is not zero?
Probably didn't understand what outer measure really is.

Comment: Are you sure? The set of limit points is the entire closed ball itself. Also, when you say outer measure, do you mean Lebesgue outer measure?

Comment: I meant only measure of set of limits points(don't know why i said outer measure). Because I am supposed to use that if set is bounded than it is measurable if and only the measure of set of limit points is $0$. But not sure how to prove that?

Comment: Should I use that this set is compact and than we can find a finite subcover for it. So since Lebesque measure is $0$ than Jordan measure is $0$ as well(and measure of set of limit points).